# extract important features for train and test after applying random forest

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using random forest for feature selection (fist 100 most important features).
This is the code that I am using;

```
RandomForest_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,n_jobs=-1)
    RandomForest_model.fit(train_x,train_y)
    RandomForest_model.score(train_x,train_y)
    indices = RandomForest_model.feature_importances_.argsort()[:100]
    train_100_x= train.iloc[:,indices]
    test_100_y = test_100_y.iloc[:,indices]
```

My problem is that I the train and the test columns are not matching.

See the pic:

Picture of first columns in train and test:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is it a more efficient way to do it?

This is the [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-value-prediction-challenge)  that I have downloaded the train & test dataset from.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code incluidng the split for train and test

Comment: I did not split it yet in this phase. It is from a competition in Kaggle where I download the test and the train dataset separate. I was thinking to make the selection both in train and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try subsetting to your new train and test data sets using column names and not indices

```
RandomForest_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300,n_jobs=-1)
RandomForest_model.fit(train_x,train_y)

importance_df=pd.DataFrame({'feature':train_x.columns, 'importance':RandomForest_model.feature_importances_})
#sort feature importance data frame
importance_df.sort_values('importance', ascending=False, inplace=True)
#select 100 most important features
features= importance_df.feature[:100]
#
train_100_x= train_x.loc[:,features]
test_100_x = test_x.loc[:,features]
```